# Adding row level permission tag configuration to a dataset

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I am trying to embed an AWS QuickSight dashboard for anonymous access. For that dataset used in the dashboard must have tags that specify row level security. From what I see the only way to do this is via `update-data-set` cli command (or related API request). But this is insane - for this command to work I have to specify additional parameters like dataset name or even physical table map. But I have no intention to modify those, I just need to add RLS tags. Is there a straightforward way to add RLS tags to an existing dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up generating skeleton JSON for `update-data-set` via `--generate-cli-skeleton` parameter, then filling it with data from `describe-data-set` command, and adding block

```
    "RowLevelPermissionTagConfiguration": {
        "Status": "ENABLED",
        "TagRules": [
            {
                "TagKey": "my_tag",
                "ColumnName": "my_column"
            }
        ]
    }
```

and supplying this resulting JSON file via `update-data-set --cli-input-json file://thatfile.json`
Cumbersome, but it worked.